# Export Javascript source block to script tag in HTML when exporting Org file to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export

To avoid the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), let me say that what I actually want is to embed Javascript code into `<script>` tags in the HTML files produced via Org mode export, in such a way that (1) the Javascript code is included in the Org file (not a separate Javascript file), and (2) it is very easy to edit the Javascript in a Javascript specific major mode. The question title is only one way to achieve that.

Currently to embed Javascript in the resulting exported HTML I use:

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<script type="text/javascript">
 // javascript code goes here
</script>
#+END_EXPORT
```

That works fine, of course, but I'd like to edit the Javascript code in a Javascript major mode. Using `C-'` on an HTML block sensibly opens a buffer in HTML mode. So I've been using temp buffers I manually open and put in Javascript mode.

To embed code in an Org file that's conveniently editable in the correct major mode, you can use source blocks. Is there a way to get that Javascript code to export into a `<script>` tag? Or some other convenient way to get what I want?

---

EDIT: Updated the `#+BEGIN_HTML` to `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html` for the shiny new Org 9.0, per @mutbuerger's suggestion.

Comment: But do you get js from `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html` is shown in the resulting HTML file just like text ? Because I do :( 
What I get is 
`<div class="export">
<p>
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
</p>
</div>`

Comment: What version of Org do you have, @DimaFomin? That syntax is only used in version 9 and higher. The result you got sounds like version 8. You can find out the version by running `M-x org-version`.

Comment: Аrhhh! Thank you! 
You are right! Mine org-vesion is 8.2.10 :( This strange for me that it's not that fresh cause I've copied my Emacs just a week ago, it's itself 25.3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I just found my ideal approach: add a new language to babel! It's much easier than I thought. Here's how you add `inline-js`, the language that you edit in some JavaScript major mode and "evaluate" by wrapping in a `<script>` tag!

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("inline-js" . javascript)) ;; js2 if you're fancy
(defvar org-babel-default-header-args:inline-js
  '((:results . "html")
    (:exports . "results")))
(defun org-babel-execute:inline-js (body _params)
  (format "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n%s\n</script>" body))
```

Now you can write blocks like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC inline-js
  console.log("Hello World!");
#+END_SRC
```

That block exports like this:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("Hello World!");
</script>
#+END_EXPORT
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to look at ob-js, @mutbuerger, it made me find out how to add languages to Babel and when I saw how easy it was, I decided to do what's in this answer. (By the way, one could probably add a `:results script` option to ob-js that outputs a script instead of evaluating.)

Comment: This is really clever.

Comment: Oh, you can award a bounty to one answer and accept another! In that case, I'll follow your suggestion and accept this one, @mutbuerger. (It is, after all, what I'll use in my files.)

Answer (score 13):

It's worth mentioning that Org 9.0 is out and the `#+BEGIN_HTML` syntax you used is [replaced](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html) with `#+BEGIN_EXPORT language` for export blocks.

There are different ways to achieve what you want, I'm using Org-babel's noweb references here. The syntax `<<inline-js>>` inserts the literal javascript block before the elisp code block is evaluated:

```
#+name: inline-js
#+begin_src javascript :exports none
console.log('Test');
#+end_src

#+begin_src elisp :noweb yes :exports results :results html
(concat
 "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
 "<<inline-js>>\n"
 "</script>")
#+end_src

#+results:
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('Test');
</script>
#+END_EXPORT

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

This is the exported document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- ... -->

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('Test');
</script>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The following may be more appropriate if you reuse the elisp block a lot:

```
#+name: inline-js
#+begin_src elisp :exports none :results html :var blk=""
(concat
 "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
 (cadr (org-babel-lob--src-info blk))
 "\n"
 "</script>")
#+end_src

#+name: foo
#+begin_src javascript :exports none
console.log('foo');
#+end_src

#+call: inline-js("foo")

#+name: bar
#+begin_src javascript :exports none
console.log('bar');
#+end_src

#+call: inline-js("bar")
```

Comment: Good! Can I reuse the Emacs Lisp source block? I mean, name it and have it take the name of the Javascript source block as a parameter? (I'm not familiar with noweb.)

Comment: It's a little annoying that I'll have all the JavaScript code appear twice in the Org file, but I guess I can keep the html export block folded most of the time and not see it.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate the js code (i.e. evaluate the elisp blocks in the buffer), the export engine expands the result anyway.

Comment: Oh, that's right: I don't know why I thought I had to evaluate the blocks before callign export. Thanks a lot. For this new version, I think I'll just name the source block, put it in my library of Babel and then just use `#+call: inline-js("foo") :exports results :results html` in the Org files.

Comment: You're right, that's even better.

Comment: Lovely, @mutbuerger! When I wrote my previous comment I thought that maybe you'd have to annotate each `#+call` site with `:exports results :results html`, but it works to put it just in the definition of the `inline-js` source block!

Comment: This is definitely comfortable to use. The only thing I think could make it better is to not have to name the blocks.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with my [minor modification of your code](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28427/2221). I'll wait a couple of days to not discourage further innovation from others but if no vastly superior approach arises, I'll award you the bounty. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the idea of removing the names - especially with a lot of src blocks in the buffer. You will miss out easy src block navigation with `org-babel-goto-named-src-block` for example. Other than your modifications it may be worth looking into `ob-js` (requires either node.js or mozrepl) - haven't used it myself, though. I'm not sure what the `#+results` from ob-js look like, but one could easily alter the output with a `:post` function.

Comment: Well, with the change I made you still *can* name blocks if you want too, you just don't *have* to. And if you name them, you don't repeat the name when you call `inline-js`.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is really a comment on @mutbuerger's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28387/2221). I'm posting it here because comments can't and shouldn't contain blocks of code. I figured out how to avoid the need for inventing names for the JavaScript blocks:

```
#+name: inline-js
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports none :results html
  (format
   "<script type =\"text/javascript\">\n%s\n</script>\n"
   (save-excursion
     (org-babel-next-src-block)
     (cadr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))
#+end_src

#+call: inline-js()
#+begin_src javascript :exports none
console.log('foo');
#+end_src

#+call: inline-js()
#+begin_src javascript :exports none
console.log('bar');
#+end_src
```

I initially tried to use `org-babel-previous-src-block` and to keep the `#+call: inline-js()`'s *after* the JavaScript blocks as in mutbuerger's answer, but that doesn't work because by the time the Org exporter get's to the `#+call` line it has already removed the JavaScript block from the buffer (because of the `:exports none`)! Ah, the joys of stateful programming.